# How to create a Data Grid for Android?

Tags: android, datagrid

My app has to display data in a 2D grid.The grid can have multiple rows and columns (10 by 10 or 100 by 44). And the grid must display the column and row names.

Basically I want something like the DataGridView from Windows Form and WPF.

Please provide help. Thank you.

Comment: Here is a Native Android datagrid component, it is quite similar to the Windows Forms DataGridView, and provides most of its functionality.  androidjetpack.com/Home/AndroidDataGrid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have some determined number of rows and columns and that number is not big, when you might be ok with [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) - just create it in the loop or by portions with some delay.
Otherwise (if required number of rows/columns is not clear or you need some specific scrolling) custom control would be needed.

Comment: Yes, when working with TableLayout. If You're going to create own view for this purpose, then it should be possible to create own adapter for it.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a `TableLayout`, dynamically add `TableRow` with as many `TextView`s that corresponds to the columns that you wish to add. In order to make the grid look you should add a shape drawable as the background drawable of each `TextView` with white lines in order to have cells.

Sample:
in the layout.xml:

```
...
<TableLayout id="grid" *other properties*/>
...
```

a simple object Data that has all the necessary properties:

```
class Data {
  ArrayList<Row> rows;
  ArrayList<Column> column;
  //or some other properties you might need
}
```

in the `Activity`:

```
private void fillGrid(Data dat,) {
  for(int i=0; i<dat.getRows().size(); i++) {
     TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
     //set row
     for(int j=0; j<dat.getColumns().size(); j++) {
         TextView actualData = new TextView(this);
         //set properties
         row.addView(actualData);
     }
     tableLayout.addView(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a listview and add data in it .

Here is one example in response to another question 
[Populating a table with an array of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160061/android-populating-a-table-with-an-array-of-data)