# Populating a table with an array of data

Tags: android, listview, android-tablelayout, populate

I want to set up a table which has a fixed amount of columns, and an X amount of rows with The first row listing the contents of each column. For example, one column will be 'Name' and a second column will be 'Age', then there will be an X amount of rows which store the data. Is there any way that I can set up arrays for this data elsewhere, and automatically create/fill the rows of the table with this data. I've done this previously with a more simple example using a Custom Adapter but I'm not quite sure how to go about this with a table involved. I'm quite stuck and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ListView` basically acts as a row within any table of data. You should create a POJO with all the attributes you want to display in a row. You can create create a custom xml layout for the data, which would probably by a horizontal `LinearLayout` that corresponds to your columns.

POJO

```
public class MyData {
    public String Name;
    public int Age;
    // More data here
}
```

ListView item layout (layout_list_item.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Age"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Main Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:text="Name" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:text="Age" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="+@id/MyDataListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

     </LinearLayout>
```

You then need a custom adapter which sets the fields in the list view with the values from your POJO. There are plenty of tutorials on the internet for this.

Comment: Thanks for that! Would you by any chance have a link to said tutorial which you approve of? Thanks

Comment: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Answer (score 2):

I think inside the table layout create the tablerow as below

```
<TableLayout
---
>
<TableRow
--
>
<Textview
for name
/>
<Textview
...for age
/>

</TableRow>
<TableRow
--
>
<Listview
for name
/>
<Listview
...for age
/>

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

and populate the listview with a simple arrayadapter with your fixed data.

this's simple if you have textviews only in your listview you can use

```
ArrayAdapter ad=new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item1,namearray); list1.setAdapter(ad);

ArrayAdapter ad=new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item1,agearray); list2.setAdapter(ad);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I've already been able to achieve this. What I want to know is how I can automatically fill the data in each row using an Adapter of some kind which is linked to an array of objects. Any help greatly appreciated !